# How to pass a specific Java script object to PHP, without it outputting "array"?

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, post

I wrote out a sample section of the JS data below. I want it to output "donkeyMan" but it outputs the word "Array" so I am not sure how to grab that exact data. And magic suggest is just a plugin for bootstrap that does dropdowns.

html

```
   <form action="demo.php" method="post">
        <input class="form-control" name = "character" id="character">
        <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
   </form>
```

My javascript within the html

```
   $('#character').magicSuggest({
    placeholder: 'Enter a CharacterName...',
    data: [{
        name: 'MonkeyMan',
        pic: '<img src="tinyIcons/donkeySquare.png">'
          }],
    valueField: 'name',
    valueField: 'pic',
      });
```

Simple PHP code:

```
 $pp = $_POST["character"];

 if (isset($pp)) {echo $pp;}
  else
     {echo "nothing there";}
```

Comment: try `$pp = $_POST["character"];

 if (isset($pp)) {echo $pp[0];}
  else
     {echo "nothing there";}`

Comment: just printed out the png thats all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#character').magicSuggest({
   placeholder: 'Enter a CharacterName...',
   data: [{
     name: 'MonkeyMan',
     pic: '<img src="tinyIcons/donkeySquare.png">'
       }],
   valueField: 'name'
});
```

---

```
$pp = $_POST["character"];
if(isset($pp)) {
    if(is_array($pp)) {
        if(isset($pp["name"])) {
            echo $pp["name"]; 
        } else {
            # just see what's in the array
            print_r($pp);
        }
    } else {
        echo $pp;
    }
} else {
    echo "nothing there";
}
```

Comment: the hole thing didnt print out anything , so i just put print_p($pp)and it put Array ( [0] => (outputs the png)). It doesnt say the name at all.

Comment: You defined valueField two times and it shouldn't be `pic`.

Comment: Any Way I Can put Both The Name ANd the Picture In The Array?

Comment: I don't think so, magicSuggest seems to let you design special multiselect selectboxes but returns a normal array of form field values, normally IDs, here: character[] with content of what you defined as valueField. Have a look at the documentation: http://nicolasbize.com/magicsuggest/doc.html